# How to combine php and javascript to get an array to ticker tape

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a javascript ticker tape which is like this:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
//var message="Indigo-TX software Company Online Share Trading and     mutual funds"

var message="<?php print $test1;?>"

k=message.length
spacer=".... ..."
pos=0;
function scrolling()
{
   document.form12.text1.value=message.substring(pos,k)+spacer+message.substring    (0,pos);
pos++;
if(pos>k){pos=0;};
setTimeout("scrolling()",200);
}
</script>
```

In this part of Java script above you see i refer to a php variable...

```
<?php
$StockMarketAPI2 = new StockMarketAPI;
$StockMarketAPI2->symbol = array('BABA', 'GPRO', 'NFLX');


<?php $test1 = ($StockMarketAPI2->getData());
```

But now the ticker tape only prints: ...array...

How should I change it ?
To get it to print the contents which is normally like so:

```
Array
(
    [-0.12 - -0.15%] => Array

    (
        [name] => Alibaba Group Holding Limited A
        [price] => 81.17
        [change] => -0.12
        [volume] => 17910494
    )

[-0.10 - -0.20%] => Array
    (
        [name] => GoPro, Inc.
        [price] => 49.98
        [change] => -0.10
        [volume] => 4560482
    )

[+0.53 - +0.10%] => Array
    (
        [name] => Netflix, Inc.
        [price] => 557.03
        [change] => +0.53
        [volume] => 1272298
    )
)
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: One does not simply `print $array;`

Comment: that is not helping. consider me as a newbee...

Comment: here is an example: http://testenvansoftware.nl/test12/index3.php

Comment: it said. <script language="javascript"> what do you mean Dan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example : http://testenvansoftware.nl/test12/index3.php

I see, ->getData() is NOT part of php.net functions... right?

it is part of class.stockMarketAPI2.php

ok, yes it is, i see now:

```
public function getData($symbol='', $stat='') {

        if (is_array($this->symbol)) {
            $symbol = implode("+", $this->symbol); //The Yahoo! API will     take multiple symbols
        }

        if($symbol) $this->_setParam('symbol', $symbol);
        if($stat) $this->_setParam('stat', $stat);

        $data = $this->_request();

       if(!$this->history) {
        if ($this->stat === 'all') { 
            foreach ($data as $item) {

                //Add to $return[$symbol] array. Indice 23 is the symbol.
                $return[$item[23]] = array(
                    'name'                      =>      strip_tags($item[20]),
                    'price'                       =>      strip_tags($item[0]),
                    'change'                      =>      strip_tags($item[1]),
                    'volume'                      =>      strip_tags($item[2])

                    //'avg_daily_volume'            =>  strip_tags($item[3]),
                    //'stock_exchange'              =>  strip_tags($item[4]),
                    //'market_cap'                  =>  strip_tags($item[5]),
                    //'book_value'                  =>  strip_tags($item[6]),
                    //'ebitda'                      =>  strip_tags($item[7]),
                    //'dividend_per_share'          =>  strip_tags($item[8]),
                    //'dividend_yield'              =>  strip_tags($item[9]),
                    //'earnings_per_share'          =>  strip_tags($item[10]),
                    //'fiftytwo_week_high'          =>  strip_tags($item[11]),
                    //'fiftytwo_week_low'           =>  strip_tags($item[12]),
                    //'fiftyday_moving_avg'         =>  strip_tags($item[13]),
                    //'twohundredday_moving_avg'    =>  strip_tags($item[14]),
                    //'price_earnings_ratio'        =>  strip_tags($item[15]),
                    //'price_earnings_growth_ratio' =>  strip_tags($item[16]),
                    //'price_sales_ratio'           =>  strip_tags($item[17]),
                    //'price_book_ratio'            =>  strip_tags($item[18]),
                    //'short_ratio'                 =>  strip_tags($item[19]),
                    //'name'                        =>  strip_tags($item[20])
                );
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($data as $item)
                $return[] = array($this->stat => $item);
        }
    } elseif(is_array($this->history)) {
        $return = $data;
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: for the persons interested, the full code of this can be founda at:  http://www.benmarshall.me/php-stock-market-api/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code -

```
var messageJson='<?php echo json_encode( $test1 ); ?>';
var message = JSON.parse( messageJson );
```

Comment: and use message as a java-script array

Comment: Thanks for the input Prakash, I tried it, it results in an empty ticker... nothing is scrolled....

Comment: Prakash, I am showing the source now.. maybe that helps?   http://testenvansoftware.nl/test12/index3.php

Comment: Did you test print_r(  $test1 ); die;  before this code, It must show $test1 array, Is it okey ?

Comment: $test1 must not be blank here

Comment: got it to work Prakash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028325/how-to-get-only-specific-values-out-of-an-custom-public-function/30029139#30029139

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going into details because this post is 4 months old at the time I'm writing this but this task is simple...

Step 1
jquery-ticker from list...

Step 2
your best way to get data... I'm using fgetcsv

Step 3 
Instead of building a table build list

Step 4
Hook up your style

And there's your data driven ticker tape.. Got to get back to work but this site has been good to me, and wanted to give back.